# Can I use other methods beside HTTP-Auth to get Delicious.com API calls authenticated?

Tags: api, delicious-api

I'm developing an app that interacts with delicious.com using its API. For my application it is important use OAuth to authenticate delicious.com API calls. I read the doc at http://delicious.com/developers and nothing is said about other authentication methods beside HTTP-Auth.

My confusion is that when I google a little, some posts appear to reference a version 2 of the API that allows OAuth, but I found no doc about OAuth - Delicious API neither Version 2 - Delicious API.

Any experts know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reproducing here delicious support reply:

> Hi Frank,
>
> Thanks for your email.
>
> While we only currently offer HTTP-Auth support, we are working on
>   oAuth and hope to have a release ready within the next few months.
>
> Please let us know should you have any other questions or need further
>   assistance.
>
> Cheers, Team Delicious

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that while Delicious was part of the Yahoo! empire they integrated the authentication with the Yahoo user model which used OAuth.  Now that Delicious is no longer part of Yahoo! they obviously cannot use that, so have dropped back to HTTP-Auth.

Cheers,
Rupert.